# Знаки сравнения в переменной javaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var symbol = ['==', '>=']
var a = 2
var b = 1 
if (a symbol[0] b) {
....
}
```

Как написать такой код синтаксически верным и рабочим? Нужно чтобы знак сравнения был в переменной, которая будет переопределяться. Или такое не возможно?

Comment: В JS нельзя перегружать операторы, тем более ещё и извлекать их из массива. Только `eval`, что есть страшное зло и ответ @tutankhamun.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, почему не поможет? _`if (eval(\`a ${symbol[0]} b\`)) {`_

Comment: @Grundy ну да, поможет. Что-то про самый простой способ вызвать `eval` я и не подумал :) И да, такой `eval` - и правда зло xD

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну тут как сказать, если только свой код, но тут большой разницы не будет

Answer (score 3):

Не взлетит. Имхо только использовать `eval`, но я бы не стал. В качестве варианта я бы сделал хеш функций сравнения и подставлял аргументы в выбранную по ключу функцию (в качестве ключа - операция)

```
var oper = {
    '==': function (a, b) { return a == b; }, 
    '>=': function (a, b) { return a >= b; }
};
var a = 2;
var b = 1;
var ix = '==';
if (oper[ix](a, b)) {
....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[tutankhamun](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177613/tutankhamun) Предложил занести операции сравнения в хеш - но в некоторых случаях можно вовсе не использовать их строковую форму - а использовать напрямую функции.

Ваш код может выглядеть так (я использую [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) для упрощения, обратите внимание что они не работают в IE и Safari):

```
var symbol = [
    (a, b) => a == b,
    (a, b) => a >= b
]
var a = 2
var b = 1 
if (symbol[0](a, b)) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: я бы переменовал symbol в какой-нибудь comparers :-)

Comment: Плюсую Grundy.  Чтобы не тратить когнитивных усилий на понимание при чем же тут тип Symbol

Comment: @Grundy имя переменной я взял из вопроса

Comment: @Утка ^^^^^^^^^